# Barra de progresso em segunda janela

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou criando um sistema que pega os arquivos de um servidor e copia para o a minha máquina. Trabalho em uma empresa de softwares e como não podemos instalar sistemas de fora, resolvi criar o próprio. O sistema está até funcionando, porém estou melhorando ele.

Preciso inserir uma barra de progresso para que seja possível acompanhar o status da cópia. Criei uma outra janela Form2.cs onde está a barra, 
configurei a chamada da janela, porém estou na dúvida na hora de realizar a chamada da barra para o carregamento.

Segue o código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Chamar outra janela 

        atualizainstaladores2.Form2 barra = new atualizainstaladores2.Form2();
        barra.ShowDialog();

        if (!Directory.Exists(@"E:\InstaladoresSHOP\Sistemas"))
        {
            //criar o diretório caso não exista
            // copiar de PDV todos os arquivos com .exe no final 
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"E:\InstaladoresShop\Sistemas\Shop\PDV");
            string[] PDV = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\thale\Downloads\Sistemas\Sistemas\PDV", "*.exe");
            foreach (string item in PDV)
            {

                File.Copy(item, @"E:\InstaladoresShop\Sistemas\Shop\PDV\" + Path.GetFileName(item));
            }



            MessageBox.Show("Diretorio PDV atualizado com Sucesso!!");
        }
```

Comment: 1- A execução do código vai parar no `ShowDialog` até o form `barra` ser fechado, então você não pode abri-lo como um dialogo modal. 2- Durante a cópia, a tela vai estar travada. O ideal é que essa tarefa seja feita em outra thread, enquanto é exibido na tela o progresso. 3- Dê uma olhada no BackgroundWorker, e considere exibir a barra de progresso no mesmo `Form` em que está acontecendo a cópia.

Comment: Implementei o que o @RovannLinhalis comentou acima na minha resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já que deseja um segundo `Form` com uma barra de progresso, sugiro que transfira o código da cópia dos arquivos para esse segundo `Form`. No momento em que chamar ele, o processo de cópia será iniciado e a tela será atualizada com o progresso da cópia.

Coloque o seguinte código no seu `Form2`:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    StartCopy();
}

private void StartCopy()
{
    string[] PDV = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\thale\Downloads\Sistemas\Sistemas\PDV", "*.exe");

    // Coloca a quantidade de arquivos como valor máximo do ProgressBar
    progressBar1.Maximum = PDV.Length;
    progressBar1.Value = 0;

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
       if (!Directory.Exists(@"E:\InstaladoresSHOP\Sistemas"))
       {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"E:\InstaladoresShop\Sistemas\Shop\PDV");

        // Inicia a cópia
        foreach (string item in PDV)
        {
            File.Copy(item, @"E:\InstaladoresShop\Sistemas\Shop\PDV\" + Path.GetFileName(item));
            progressBar1.Invoke((Action)delegate { progressBar1.Value += 1; });
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Diretorio PDV atualizado com Sucesso!!");
      }
    });
}
```

*Não esqueça de adicionar um `ProgressBar` com o nome de `progressBar1` no seu Form2. O mesmo será a a barra de progresso.*

Perceba que existe um `Task.Run` no código acima. Isso se deve pelo fato de que quando necessitamos fazer tarefas pesadas, como por exemplo, copiar arquivos de um lado para outro, esse tipo de tarefa deve ser executada em outra `Thread` diferente da `UI Thread`. E é exatamente que o `Task.Run` faz. Executa o código informado em uma nova `thread`, uma `thread` em segundo plano.

Perceba também que no `ProgressBar` utilizado, `progressBar1`, eu utilizo um `Invoke`. Isso se deve ao fato de que para atualizar o `ProgressBar`, precisamos executar a modificação na `UI Thread`. E é exatamente isso que o `Invoke` está fazendo.

No seu `Form1`, o que deve fazer é apenas chamar o `Form2`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormProgress progress = new FormProgress();
    progress.Show();
}
```

Comment: eu só mudaria pra não charmar o `GetFiles` duas vezes, chamaria uma vez só e armazenaria os valores =]

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Bem observado. Até porque eu não estava fazendo o teste se a pasta existia ou não, o que poderia gerar erro. Coloquei em apenas um lugar. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou perfeitamente. muito obrigado